# How to add my application folder into control panel?

Tags: java, windows, swing, deployment

I have created a installation wizard using Java.  It will install my application folder in to the desired location and its shortcut will send to Desktop and the application list.  But I need to send my application folder in to control panel.

How to add my application folder into control panel?

Comment: you mean to say when you install the application then after installation it should reflect into the add or remove list of programs right?

Comment: *"I have created a installation wizard using Java."*  Deploy the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can already do what your installer does (download/install the app. and add a desktop shortcut & start menu item) and will also show the app. in the control panel ('Uninstall a program') and much more besides (read the link).   Further, JWS works on OS X, *nix **and** Windows.

Comment: Who are you replying to?  Add @eatSleepCode (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: *"Can you send me the code"*  1) It is not 'code' but a JNLP file (it is a form of XML) you need .  2) I don't "send you the code" for free, if you want to continue discussing it on SO, fine.  Otherwise get a PayPal..

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1 :** First clean and build your project and make an executable jar file.

**STEP 2 :** In-order to create a set-up for your application, Use [**Install Creator 2.0.34**](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-9655-clickteam-install-creator) (a third party software for creating set-up for applications) and follow the steps said in Install creator.

**STEP 3 :** After creating the setup, Install it in your system.

**STEP 4 :** After Installing your application you can find your app in **Program Files** as well in **Add/Remove Programs** in the **Control Panel**

Otherwise Deploy your application in **Java Web-Start** and create a **JNLP**